# iTunes Connect: How to tell what device was used in universal app purchase in appstore?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store

I have a universal app (iPad & iPhone) on the appstore. I'm wondering how I can tell if a purchase was made by an iPad or an iPhone user. In the sales & trends section in itunes connect I cannot find this information. Any ideas? 
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible.

Indeed many users have both devices.  Many users have more than one of each device.

Many (most?) users make the purchase only on their Mac or PC (iTunes) rather than on a device.

Afterwards they may sync it on to all of their devices. Or, they may sync it on to only one of their devices.

Or they may sync it on to their iPhone, and one year later sync it on to their iPad and remove it from their iPhone.

(Conceivably a user could own NO iPads or iFones, and just buy it on iTunes!  Perhaps assuming they will get an iPod in the future to play the game.)

It's interesting to note that you can't even tell how MANY devices your app is installed on.

(These days, almost everyone has more than one iDevice, per, iTunes purchasing account.) (And I guess most people realise you can temporarily log in as your spouse or whatever so you can both both load a network game one of you has bought.)

It could well be that for every 10,000 sales, on average your app is on 20,000 (say) devices. It's an unknown.

Note that if you use **analytics** -- whether something like Flurry or your own -- you can to some extent get answers to such questions once it is actually running. But not in the app store.